# Visual FoxPro (VFP) CTOBIN and BINTOC Functions - Equivalent In .Net

Tags: c#, encoding, ascii, smartcard, visual-foxpro

We are rewriting some applications previously developed in Visual FoxPro and redeveloping them using .Net ( using C# )

Here is our scenario:
Our application uses smartcards. We read in data from a smartcard which has a name and number. The name comes back ok in readable text but the number, in this case '900' comes back as a 2 byte character representation (131 & 132) and look like this - ƒ„

Those 2 special characters can be seen in the extended Ascii table.. now as you can see the 2 bytes are 131 and 132 and can vary as there is no single standard extended ascii table ( as far as I can tell reading some of the posts on here )

So... the smart card was previously written to using the BINTOC function in VFP and therefore the 900 was written to the card as ƒ„. And within foxpro those 2 special characters can be converted back into integer format using CTOBIN function.. another built in function in FoxPro..

So ( finally getting to the point ) - So far we have been unable to convert those 2 special characters back to an int ( 900 ) and we are wondering if this is possible in .NET to read the character representation of an integer back to an actual integer.

Or is there a way to rewrite the logic of those 2 VFP functions in C#?

**UPDATE**:
After some fiddling we realise that to get 900 into 2bytes we need to convert 900 into a 16bit Binary Value, then we need to convert that 16 bit binary value into a decimal value.

So as above we are receiving back 131 and 132 and their corresponding binary values as being 10000011 ( decimal value 131 ) and 10000100 ( decimal value 132 ).
When we concatenate these 2 values to '1000001110000100' it gives the decimal value 33668 however if we removed the leading 1 and transform '000001110000100' to decimal it gives the correct value of 900...

Not too sure why this is though...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Problem Solved. We converted the number 900 into binary, took the values from 9 - 16 ( invlusive ) as our second byte and took the remaining values and updated that with with a leading 1 as the number is > 127. This works in both directions converting any number > 127 ( and less than 32,7?? whatever the ceiling value is )

Comment: Example : 900 in binary = 1110000100. Take the last 8 digits ( 10000100 ) and convert to decimal = 132. Take the first 2 digits (11) and apply 5 subsequent 0's and start the binary value with a 1 so it will look like this - 10000011. Convert this to decimal and it is 131. Now to get the 131, 132 decimal values back into a single binary value to convert back to decimal we convert them seperately and join them to give us 1000001110000100. Now, just replace the 1 in position 1 with a 0 to get the original 16bit binary value, we only need the 1 at the start if we are working with 2 x bit chunks

Comment: If you think you've answered your question adequately, feel free to post it as an answer to your question. This will allow you to mark this question as answered.

Comment: You could rewrite the whole of that Question as "How do I convert a 16 bit signed integer stored using the VFP BINTOC() function into a decimal using C#" which would make it much more useful to other readers and less likely to be closed as too localized.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like VFP is storing your value as a signed 16 bit (short) integer. It seems to have a strange changeover point to me for the negative numbers but it adds 128 to 8 bit numbers and adds 32768 to 16 bit numbers.

So converting your 16 bit numbers from the string should be as easy as reading it as a 16 bit integer and then taking 32768 away from it. If you have to do this manually then the first number has to be multiplied by 256 and then add the second number to get the stored value. Then take 32768 away from this number to get your value.

Examples:

```
131 * 256 = 33536
33536 + 132 = 33668
33668 - 32768 = 900
```

You could try using the C# conversions as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131059.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw38dw27.aspx to do at least some of the work for you but if not it shouldn't be too hard to code the above manually.

Answer (score 0):

It's a few years late, but here's a working example.

```
public ulong CharToBin(byte[] s)
{
  if (s == null || s.Length < 1 || s.Length > 8)
    return 0ul;

  var v = s.Select(c => (ulong)c).ToArray();
  var result = 0ul;
  var multiplier = 1ul;
  for (var i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
  {
    if (i > 0)
      multiplier *= 256ul;

    result += v[i] * multiplier;
  }

  return result;
}
```

This is a VFP 8 and earlier equivalent for CTOBIN, which covers your scenario. You should be able to write your own BINTOC based on the code above. VFP 9 added support for multiple  options like non-reversed binary data, currency and double data types, and signed values. This sample only covers reversed unsigned binary like older VFP supported.

Some notes:

- The code supports 1, 2, 4, and 8-byte values, which covers all
  unsigned numeric values up to `System.UInt64`.
- Before casting the
  result down to your expected numeric type, you should verify the
  ceiling. For example, if you need an Int32, then check the result
  against `Int32.MaxValue` before you perform the cast.
- The sample avoids the complexity of string encoding by accepting a
  byte array. You would need to understand which encoding was used to
  read the string, then apply that same encoding to get the byte array
  before calling this function. In the VFP world, this is frequently
  `Encoding.ASCII`, but it depends on the application.